# I want an if statement to add a rectangle to a list, when a condition is met, but it keeps adding them until the condition is false

Tags: python, pygame

I'm very new to pygame and python in general, and I'm trying to make a simple game. In the code, I made a class Enemy, and an instance of it enemy, here.

```
class Enemy:
def __init__(self):
    self.list = []
    self.size = 20
    self.x = random.randint(0 , WIDTH - self.size)
    self.y = random.randint(70 , HEIGHT - self.size)
    self.new_enemy = pygame.Rect(self.x , self.y , self.size , self.size)

def add_enemy(self):
    if score % 5 == 0 and score != 0:
        self.list.append(self.new_enemy)
        print(enemy.list)
        #to see if it works
enemy = Enemy()
```

But when I run enemy.add_enemy(), while score == 5 (or 10, 15, etc), it adds not just one but tons of items to the list. Is there a way around this? help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is because after your first enemy is created, your score will still match the `if` statement, so another will be created, etc. Consider rewriting your code so `add_enemy` is called whenever your score is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i still have doubts about this, since i dont have more of the code.

But fundamentally what's happening here is that `self.newenemy` is being delared and created, then in `add_enemy` you run `self.list.append(self.newenemy)` which is essentially adding the same object into the list. so the list has n objects, but they are all the "same" as in not copy or duplicates, but the exact same. so if you were to "kill" `list[0]` enemy they all would die.

EDIT: Additionally, your `randint` will always generate the same values, so x and y will always be the same once the class gets created.

try changing your code to something like this. NOTE the return in `add_enemy` after the append is done.

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
        self.size = 20
    
    def add_enemy(self):
        if score % 5 == 0 and score != 0:
            self.list.append(pygame.Rect(self.get_rand_x() , self.get_rand_y() , self.size , self.size))
            return
        
    def get_rand_x(self):
        return random.randint(0 , WIDTH - self.size)

    def get_rand_y(self):
        return random.randint(70 , HEIGHT - self.size)


enemy = Enemy()
enemy.add_enemy()
print(enemy.list)
```

Comment: ohh and as for having too many enemies in the list, update the add_enemy call to only be done after the score is updated.